# How to get values by name with JAX-RS(JSR339)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

Colleagues in my office are developping a web system with JAX-RS（JSR339).
I need to get values by name(string) and I asked them to. But they have few idea.
I'm quite new to JAX-RS and googled it and I learned that
JAX-RS injects values to variables by annotations like

```
@Path("/sample")
public interface SampleResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/hello/{message}")
    String sayHello(@PathParam("message") String message);
}
```

However I want to get values by name at runtime like

```
@Path("/sample")
public interface SampleResource {
    String name = "message"; // dynamic value

    @GET
    @Path("/hello/{" + name + "}")
    String sayHello(@PathParam(name) String message);
}
```

Perhaps this is a wrong code. My question is how to get values by name like the example above.
(I'm afraid the sample codes aren't correct ones but I hope you grasp my idea and concerns. Thanks.)

Comment: Supposing it were possible, what would be the advantage of having the param name dynamic?

Comment: In my case I want the param names to be stored in database. I' planning to put param names and their check logic into database so that no java code needs to be changed if the names and logic may change.

Comment: Do you want do this interface or in the implemented class ?

Comment: I want to do in the corresponding implementation class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

**Example of the bean which will be used as @BeanParam**

```
public class MyBeanParam {
    @PathParam("p")
    private String pathParam;.

    public String getPathParam() {
        return pathParam;
    }
}
```

**Injection of MyBeanParam as a method parameter:**

```
@GET
String sayHello(@BeanParam MyBeanParam beanParam, String entity){
    final String pathParam = beanParam.getPathParam(); // contains injected path parameter "p"
    ...
}
```

**OR**

You can use **UriInfo** to get QueryParam. For example application see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/)

Comment: Both look very promising. I'll tell them to the colleagues tomorrow and get their comment. If OK I'll have this question answered. Pls wait. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The colleagues had time to examine the first method and said OK. Thank you very much again.